# jQuery merging select field and text input values in real time to another text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a three field form. I'd like the third field (text box) to display a combination of the first two fields ... one being a select field and the other being a text field; these values separated with a space. I have tried the following with little success.

```
<form>
    <select name="val1" id="val1">
        <option value="">Select a value</option>
        <option value="foo">foo</option>
        <option value="bar">bar</option>
    </select>
    <input name="val2" id="val2" />
    <input name="val3" id="val3" />
</form>
<script>
    $('#val1, #val2').keyup(function(){ $('#val3').val($('#val1').val()+' '+$('#val2').val()); });
<script>
```

What I'm expecting is when a user selects an option from the select field, is value would appear in the third form field and when a user types something in the second field, its value would also appear in the third field separated with a space. This would all happen in real time. Oddly enough, the jQuery code does nothing in all browsers.

Maybe something to do with the keyup() function as a select field is using the mouse only. But even if I ignore the select field and type something in the second field, it should appear in the third field alone, but it doesn't.

Comment: Did you include a reference to the JQuery library in your code before your script ?

Comment: You also need to close your script tag correctly: `</script>` instead of the second `<script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#val1` is a `select` element, the `keyup` event can't be called with that.

Instead, you neeed to use `change` event.

```
$('#val1').change(function () {
    changeThird();
});

$('#val2').keyup(function () {
    changeThird();
});

function changeThird() {
    $('#val3').val($('#val1').val() + ' ' + $('#val2').val());
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/e7ru9jao/

For `asp:TextBox`, you need to use `.attr()` if you want to get the data generated:

```
$('#val1').change(function () {
    changeThird();
});

$('#val2').keyup(function () {
    changeThird();
});

function changeThird() {
    $('#val3').attr("value", $('#val1').val() + ' ' + $('#val2').val());
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you. Is there a way to modify your script so that it reads the text value of the select field rather than the option value? EG: <option value="foo">text value</option> Now the script would get 'text value' instead of 'foo'.

Comment: Got it. $('#val3').val($('#val1 option:selected').text() + ' ' + $('#val2').val());

Comment: @Overspeed Can you click on the tick on the answer to mark the question as "answered" please ?

Comment: Strange thing is happening to the form. Using your code and the addition I added to read the option text value, the third form field is displaying the value of the first two fields correctly but when the form is submitted, the third field is blank (not saved to DB). It's as though the third field shows the data but actually has nothing to submit. If I actually type something in the third field, its data is submitted fine, just the autogenerated content is not.

Comment: @Overspeed You just need to add `value=""` in your 3rd input HTML to fix this

Comment: That didn't work. I tried value="" (text=""). When submitted it was still blank. I tried value="this is a value" and when submitted, the stored data was 'this is a value'. I didn';t mention earlier that this form is generated via asp:TextBox which uses text="" instead of value="". Maybe this jQuery code isn't compatible with this form type.

Comment: Okay ... on the asp:TextBox input I had to remove ReadOnly="true" and disabled="disabled" to get the data to be stored. Now if only I can find a way to disable the input from the user without using those controls. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Overspeed Just updated my answer for asp. Hope this will do the trick.